# Are there macros which define the ROS version?

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to add some preprocessor conditions to allow some code to build in both Cturtle and Diamondback (and others in the future). Are there defines that indicate which version code is being compiled in?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10448/are-there-macros-which-define-the-ros-version?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-06-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-30**:
It is exactly the answer. You should copy that as an answer so the question can be closed.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-06-30**:
this maybe related http://answers.ros.org/question/540/how-do-i-test-the-ros-version-in-c-code?answer=925#925?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this maybe related http://answers.ros.org/question/540/how-do-i-test-the-ros-version-in-c-code?answer=925#925? - hsu (Jun 30)

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2